# Turn off Snap-Assist-like feature in Windows 10 (for notebooks)

Tags: windows-10, accessibility, aero-snap

I googled lot around related to the following problem: I have a freshly pre-installed Windows 10 on my Dell notebook. When I start to move a window, a blue-colored assistance symbol shows up offering me to maximize the window (see the pic below):

Some kind of Snap Assist feature:

[image]

Related to my information it has nothing to do with Snap Assist - I tried to turn it off by that, no success. This blue-colored figure goes with as it's moved and if I drop the window on it accidentally, than the window get maximized (annoying feature - perhaps it's thought out for touchpads).

Comment: Did you go into the `Settings` for `Multitasking` and set `Allow the system to suggest companion windows when using Snap` to off?

Comment: It may be a Dell setting. `Right Click desktop -> Dell PremierColor -> Tune Display -> Advanced -> Display Splitter -> Uncheck the box`. I had this issue on my laptop or desktop but neither of those are a Dell. So it's hard telling which setting needs to be tweaked.

Comment: DrZoo, Respect!! Your second comment was exactly the tip, that helped me out to get rid of this annoying "Display Splitter". It might be some kind of innovation trial from Dell, but I cannot get used to it.

Comment: DrZoo, if you posted your solution as Answer, than I'd rate it as useful and mark it as the right answer. - I guess, you already have plenty of reputation :) but one more would not be bad, right? ;)

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. I'll go ahead and move it into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two blue screens above are a result of the `Display Splitter` setting in Dell's PremierColor.

To disable this setting do the following: `Right Click desktop -> Dell PremierColor -> Tune Display -> Advanced -> Display Splitter -> Uncheck the box`.

This will disable the two annoying blue boxes that appear when dragging windows.